# Initial value (0) for numeric parameterized type

Tags: scala, generics

Consider, I want to implement some function, that would apply `Long => T` to range of integers `a..b` and accumulate result of type `T` (it is exercise, not a search for effective solution)

```
def sum[T <: Number](f: Long => T)(a: Long, b: Long): T = {
  def loop(acc: T, n: Long): T = 
    if (n > b)
      acc
    else
      loop(acc + f(n), n + 1)

  loop(0, a)
}
```

It flaws at `loop(0,` complaining

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(0)
 required: T
     loop(0, a)
```

I understand why, but what are the options to give 0 of Numeric type `T` here? If any, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `Numeric` type class for your generic `T`.  This will give you access to methods `zero` and `plus` (since every `Numeric` must define these) that will allow you to generically perform a summation.

```
def sum[T](f: Long => T)(a: Long, b: Long)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = {
  def loop(acc: T, n: Long): T =
    if (n > b)
      acc
    else
      loop(num.plus(acc, f(n)), n + 1)

  loop(num.zero, a)
}
```

Btw: this is what Scala's built-in `sum` method does:

```
// from TraversableOnce
def sum[B >: A](implicit num: Numeric[B]): B = foldLeft(num.zero)(num.plus)
```

Comment: In this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4034176/978664 shown some syntactic sugar, so type param might be given as `[T : Numeric]` and `val num = implicitly[Numeric[T]]`. Just for protocol.